# Encoding from ANSI when having non-latin letters

Tags: encoding, character-encoding, arabic

I have a very old program (not a server or something on the internet) that I think it use the ANSI (Windows-1252) encoding.
The problem is that some inputs to this program are written in Arabic.

However, when I am trying to read the result, the Arabic words are written with very wired character. For example the input: "نور" is converted to "äæÑ".

The program output should contain a combination of English words and Arabic words.
E.x. It outputs "Name äæÑ" while the correct output should be something like "Name نور".
In general, the English words are correct and readable with both UTF-8 and ANSI. But the Arabic words are read for example as "���" with UTF-8 and as "äæÑ" with ANSI.

I understand that this is because ANSI doesn't have support to non-Latin letters.
but what should I do now? How can I convert them to Arabic again?

Note: I know the exact input and the exact output that this program should produce.
Note2: I don't have the source code of this program. I just want to convert the output file of this program to have the correct words or encoding.

Comment: BTW: "ANSI" do not support fully Latin scripts. "ANSI" is also a bad name. ANSI in any case is recent (ISO Latin-1 + extensions), so no more than 223 characters. I think you have an older encoding (or a different encoding). You say "mixed"? So possibly an encoding with "SHIFT" (same code may represent different characters, according a state given by control characters). You may need to open the data in a good text editor, and there try to change encoding, until you find the original encoding.

Comment: Thanks @GiacomoCatenazzi , I really have no clue about what encoding this file is written in. I tried a lot and after a while I note that the designer of the thing has this field at the beginning of the file `CHAR ANSI`. I understand that ANSI contain many thing inside it but I didn't succeed with converting it.

Comment: The problem with "ANSI" is that it's not well-defined. It could mean CP1252 or CP1256 or CP850 or a number of other code pages. None of these are actually related to the American National Standards Institute at all (other than in the sense that Microsoft tried to twist their arm into approving one of them as an ANSI standard at one point).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem now by typing in the terminal:

```
iconv -f WINDOWS-1256 -t utf8 < my_File.ged > result.ged
```

I tried to write code in java that do a similar thing but it wasn't really working with giving my the result I wanted.

I have also tried the previous terminal command but using `WINDOWS-1252` instead of `WINDOWS-1256` but it wasn't working. So, I guess it is good to try different encoding until it is working

Comment: You might want to refer to https://tripleee.github.io/8bit if you still find some code points which are not converted correctly. Searching for ن on that page suggests iso-8859-6 and a couple of marginal other code pages you could try.